# Will StreamBuilder auto off the stream in stateless widget?

Tags: dart, stream, flutter

When i using BLOC in Flutter , for Example:

```
class StreamText extends StatelessWidget {
  StreamText(
    this.stream, {
    this.style,
  });

  final Stream<dynamic> stream;
  final TextStyle style;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Text(snapshot.data.toString(), style: style);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is a Stateless widget and don't have `dispose()` method there;

and how could i off the stream or will it auto off the stream when this widget destroyed?

Comment: `"off the stream"`? what do you mean by that? `StreamController.close()`?

Comment: @pskink yep. that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a stream into a Stateless widget, you should close the stream overriding the `dispose` method of the subclassed State class associated to the Stateful widget where you have the instance of the stream. Also, in this widget, you have to check if the `snapshot.data` is **null** (and return for example a `Container()`) or you get an error since you are not passing an `initialData` to the `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: `"overriding the dispose method"` - in `StatefulWidget`? `dispose()` is a `State`'s method

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I meant on the subclass of State associated with the Statuful widget.

Comment: And how can i close the stream from Observable inside stream builder  or  stateless widget ? i have  known how to close the BehaviorSubject's stream

Answer (score 10):

No, it won't close the `Stream`, but it will close the `StreamSubscription` that is used to build the Widget.

If the `Stream` is not going to be used for anything else, the best would be to dispose the `Stream` somehow (by wrapping it on a `StatefulWidget` or by using a `BlocProvider` approach).

**If you are using a `Stream` somewhere else or you will use the `Stream` in the future you don't need to worry about leaking memory for its use on a `StreamBuilder`.** As long as you dispose it whenever everyone else stops using it.

The `StreamBuilder` itself extends from **`StreamBuilderBase` which is a `StatefulWidget`**, and it handles the `StreamSubscription` with its own `dispose` method.

This is an excerpt from the `async.dart` library.

```dart
/// State for [StreamBuilderBase].
class _StreamBuilderBaseState<T, S> extends State<StreamBuilderBase<T, S>> {
  StreamSubscription<T> _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //...
    _subscribe();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _unsubscribe();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _subscribe() {
    if (widget.stream != null) {
      _subscription = widget.stream.listen((T data) {
    //...
    }
  }

  void _unsubscribe() {
    if (_subscription != null) {
      _subscription.cancel();
      _subscription = null;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `StreamSubscription` is initialized on the `initState` and automatically canceled on the `dispose` call of the State, so the subscription used here will be always closed and you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

No, it won't auto close. In general the owner of the stream is the one who manages the stream state.

A good solution in my opinion is to make a stateful widget own your BLoCs and close the streams in its `dispose` method.

[This article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/reactive-programming-streams-bloc-6f0d2bd2d248) shows a possible way to implement this, have a look at the `BlocProvider` class.

Answer (score 5):

In Stateless widget, the StreamBuilder itself will "auto-off" when the widget will be removed from the Widget tree. You don't have to handle anything.

BUT, if you have a StreamController which sends the snapshots you should close it manually when you're done.